# Как добавить связи в oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Всем доброго времени суток, как сделать правильно связи таблиц в Oracle подскажите пожалуйста. Изучаю просто web поэтому такой скрин, не ругайтесь.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, как выставить foreign key? Т.е. для целостности всей схемы БД?

Comment: @Chubatiy да foreign key, не совсем понял второй вопрос, что значит целостность всей схемы БД ?

Comment: http://www.firststeps.ru/sql/oracle/r.php?108

Comment: @Chubatiy Нужно чтобы при изменении/удалении столбца из таблицы Role все связанные с этой строкой строки таблицы UserRole и User должны быть изменены или удалены.

Comment: Прочитайте статью, что вам @Mike порекомендовал. + Измените вопрос на то, что вы в итоге хотите получить. Мол, есть такие-то таблицы, как сделать то.....

Comment: С изменением сложно (нужно делать триггер). старайтесь делать так что бы ID никогда не менялись. А с удалением просто - при создании foreign key добавьте выражение `on delete cascade`

Comment: @Mike у меня id генерируются автоматически через тригер, и как тогда быть ? Как сделать авторизацию пользователя и его корректировку без изменений ?

Comment: @Ethernets Ну так id же генерится при создании записи и в последствии не меняется, так что никаких проблем "изменения записи" не существует

Comment: как правильно добавить `on dalete sacade` ? тоесть достаточно будет `ALTER TABLE userrole
ADD FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES role(id) on delete cascade; ` `ALTER TABLE userrole
ADD FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES user(id) on delete cascade;`

Comment: @Mike Вижу что достаточно, уже попробовал, а как наглядно посмотреть мои связи в TOAD не подскажете случайно ?

Comment: `on delete cascade` то вы правильно написали. А вот с названиями колонок явно погорячились. `.. userrole ADD FOREIGN KEY (RoleID) REFERENCES role(id) ...` И с вторым полем так же. И кстати в таблице UserRole собственное поле ID лучше убрать и сделать первичным ключем связку (userID, roleID). А иначе у вас не гарантируется, что один пользователь может иметь одну роль не более одного раза.

Comment: В toad не знаю, не работал с ним. но скорее всего раскрываете в дереве таблицу и там ключи где то есть

Comment: @Mike Если я правильно понял то лучше так : `ALTER TABLE UserRole ADD PRIMARY KEY (UserID, RoleID);` А как удалить FK  ?? я поспешил и накосячил немного )))

Comment: `alter table XXX drop constraint YYY` только вот имя констраинта вам надо узнать, вы при добавлении похоже его не задавали и оно какое то дефолтное при этом получилось ... Если в toad не найдете - то `select * from user_constraints where table_name='имя_таблицы_БОЛЬШИМИ_буквами'`